# Java design pattern: Factory vs Singleton? in case of Multithread

Tags: java, multithreading, design-patterns, factory-pattern

It is advisable to create new object wisely and use the same Object instance instead of creating a new one. I am not very much confident in deciding the solution for creation of object in following scenario. There is a SOAP service class which has several method that is responsible for multiple 
customer. Please see below a template,

```
Public class SOAPService {          
            public Object getProductList(String CustId, String endPoint){
                SOAPStub stub = new SOAPStub(endPoint);
                Object productList = stub.getProductList();
                return productList;
            }
            public Object getProductInfo(String CustId, String productId, String endPoint){
                SOAPStub stub = new SOAPStub(endPoint);
                Object productInfo = stub.getProductList(productId);
                return productInfo;
            }
    }
```

Now I have introduce a factory method to create Object for each of the customer and put it in a map but i am confused when multiple thread of a single customer would access the service class. Wouldn't the behavior of object be like a singleton OR which might cause any deadlock issue OR make the thread to wait ?Please enlighten me on this.

```
    Public class SOAPService {
        private Map<String, SOAPStub> map = new HashMap<String, SOAPStub>();
        public SOAPStub getSOAPObject(String CustId, String endPoint){
            if(map.containsKey(CustId))
                return map.get(CustId);
            else{
                SOAPStub stub = new SOAPStub(endPoint);
                map.put(custId, stub);
                return stub;
                }
        }
        public Object getProductList(String CustId, String endPoint){
            SOAPStub stub = getSOAPObject(CustId, endPoint);
            Object productList = stub.getProductList();
            return productList;
        }

        public Object getProductInfo(String CustId, String productId, String endPoint){
            SOAPStub stub = getSOAPObject(CustId, endPoint);
            Object productInfo = stub.getProductList(productId);
            return productInfo;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your HashMap is not threadsafe and it seems doubtful that the whole path you're going down will be productive. Your threads may spend all their time blocking on access to the shared pool, and the contention will get worse as load increases. Make your threads independent of each other whenever possible, even if that makes them use more memory.

In general reserve pooling for resource-intensive objects like database connections. See [this question about object pooling](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/115163/7460). Caching could be helpful to you, look into caching providers like ehcache. Rolling your own caching is more trouble than you think it will be.

Answer (score 1):

Your first code example  looks safe , but..

Yes, having a singleton object for service class "MAY" create issues only when you have a class variables which are being used by service method in read/write mode.

for example lets take a following service method

```
private int count = 0; //class variable 

public Response service(Request r ) 
{
count = r.getSomeVariable();
...
response.setParameter(count);
}
```

above method  might not be safe,  as each request will have its own thread and  also share common variable "count" when two request are called concurrently they may overwrite each other's data.

but if you are declaring count as variable in method itself it will be safe. because with each call of this method a new count variable will be allocated which will be destroyed after method call ends.

you can create new service for each request which will be safe , but, it will be an overhead in system.

Answer (score 1):

> It is advisable to create new object wisely and use the same Object
>   instance instead of creating a new one.

It is advisable **if** the performance gain is worth the induced complexity. It is, in my experience, rarely the case on modern object-oriented platforms.

Your being confused about what will happen in a multi threaded environment is enough to show that the tradeoff might not be that profitable.

My take : until you have proof that the number of objects newed up by sample #1 will unacceptably hurt performance in prod, sample #2 is premature optimization.

Answer (score 0):

I advice you make as a signleton. Factory is suitable if want to replace the implemention of SOAPService for some reason. So, the signleton implementation could be:

```
public final class SoapService {

    public static final String END_POINT = "endpoint";

    private final Map<String, InternalSOAPService> map = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap());

    // All user services int the box
    private final Map<String, InternalSOAPService> unmodifiableMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap(someServiceMapInitMethod());

    private static SoapService ourInstance = new SoapService();

    private SoapService() {
    }

    // All user services int the box. No delays.
    public static InternalSOAPService getServiceFromTheBox(final String custId) {
       return ourInstance.unmodifiableMap.get(custId);        
    }

    public static InternalSOAPService getService(final String custId) {

        InternalSOAPService service = ourInstance.map.get(custId);

        if (service == null) {
            synchronized (SoapService.class) {
                service = ourInstance.new InternalSOAPService(custId);
                if (service == null) { // Double Checked Locking
                    service = ourInstance.new InternalSOAPService(custId);
                }
                ourInstance.map.put(custId, service);
            }
        }
        return service;
    }

    public class InternalSOAPService {

        private final String custId;

        private final SOAPStub stub;

        public InternalSOAPService(final String custId) {
            this.custId = custId;
            this.stub = new SOAPStub(END_POINT); // Here could be Factory based on custId or END_POINT
        }

        public Object getProductList(){
            return stub.getProductList();
        }

        public Object getProductInfo(final String productId){
            return stub.getProductList(productId);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is good solution but don't you think it will delay in response if 2 threads of same object dispatch the request

Comment: Please, expand you question. Where do you think could be delay?

Comment: Eugene, Assume I have a customer_1 for which 2 request threads dispatched simultaneously and suppose Thread_1 request is in process and thread_2 will wait for the object instance until the thread_1 complete and releases the task. This is what I want to say that delay in response for thread 2.
but when  we have a system to create object for each of the request then Thread-1 and thread_2 request will have own object and no need to wait for release the object. What you say ?

Comment: @Bibhaw Yes thread_2 will be waiting for the lock if thread_1 got into the synchronized block. It only happends if service for custId is absent. You can create monitor not for SoapService.class as fast solution. But I advice (if it possible) to initialize map (use Collections.unmodifiableMap()) with service previously. It let you to remove synchronized block at all. It lets threads to work wothout any delay and much more faster.

Comment: @Bidhaw I added initialize map service previously with comment `// All user services int the box `